# Can headers added by Istio be too large?

Tags: http-headers, istio, azure-aks, istio-sidecar

I'm getting a "request header too large" error on my application after installing Istio. Can the additional headers added by Istio be too large?

Answer (score 2):

Requests coming to your `Pod` are handled by `Envoy` (with a sidecar). You could try to modify it's configuration to support bigger headers.

There is a Github issue that could be your starting point:

- *[Github.com: Istio: Issues: EnvoyFilter Patch doesn't work per documentation #21982: Comment 5](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/21982#issuecomment-638221202)*

> Hi all, in case it helps, with Istio 1.5, this works:
>
> `$ cat envoyfilter3.yaml`
>
> ```yaml
> apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
> kind: EnvoyFilter
> metadata:
>   name: hcm-tweaks
>   namespace: istio-system
> spec:
>   configPatches:
>   - applyTo: NETWORK_FILTER # http connection manager is a filter in Envoy
>     match:
>       context: GATEWAY
>       listener:
>         filterChain:
>           filter:
>             name: "envoy.http_connection_manager"
>     patch:
>       operation: MERGE
>       value:
>         typed_config:
>           "@type": "type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.filter.network.http_connection_manager.v2.HttpConnectionManager"
>           xff_num_trusted_hops: 5
>           max_request_headers_kb: 90
> ```
>
> Main difference versus the doc: removed WorkloadSelector, removed sni, added type_config."@type"

Please remember that this is a working example on `Istio` version `1.5`. You'll need to modify in accordance with the [Istio release notes](https://istio.io/latest/news/releases/).

---

Additional resources:

- *[Istio.io: Latest: Docs: Reference: Config: Networking: Envoy filter](https://istio.io/latest/docs/reference/config/networking/envoy-filter/)*

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Dawid Kruk . Could it possible that the headers added by Istio were so big that it caused this issue?

Comment: Without more information about your infrastructure/your application/your `Istio` configuration it could be hard to pinpoint the actual issue. I would rather go a way that your application is sending too big headers.